# CSS Menu Submenu Issues

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am making a pretty straight forward CSS dropdown style menu and I have followed a variety of online guides in doing so, however for whatever reason the submenus are always lining up with the top of the main menu rather than lining up with the LI it was opened from. I have gone over and over it and am doing the `top:0` and `left:100%` that everyone else is so I can't figure out what's wrong. Any insight would be super appreciate. I have never claimed to be a css master :) 
I made a plunker to show what I am doing: https://plnkr.co/edit/NkOAN0b5CVZFQodc5TfK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `li` should have `position: relative` to make it the context by which the sub menu is position ([plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/2Lbg7xVrAufsu3oPSjkm?p=preview)):

```
.navigation ul ul li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.5;
  float:none;
  min-width:200px;
}
```

Comment: Oh man, how did I miss that >.< You are a gentleman and a scholar. Thanks!

Comment: This 'gentleman and scholar' part made my day :) Be a nice chap and accept the answer (green v mark).